# How to check if context instance of a Fragment?

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if context is a instance of my Fragment when attaching it. It works with activities, how come it doesn't work with fragments?

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if(context instanceof MailFragment){

        }
    }
```

Doesn't work, but it works with `context instanceof MainActivity`

How do I check if context is instance of Fragment?

Comment: You can't attach fragment inside fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check `context instanceof Fragment`, because **Fragment is not a context**. but activities are.
And fragments need a context like an activity to attach them to be displayed.

And onAttach() occurs when a fragment attaches to a context.